# ¿Como cambiar this de react a this de javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Tengo una funcion para buscar elementos en una tabla:

```
export const buscador = (este,columna) => {
    var tableReg = $(este).parent("td").parent("tr").parent("thead").parent("table")[0];
    var searchText =$(este).val().toLowerCase();
    var cellsOfRow="";
    var found=false;
    var compareWith="";

    for (var i = 1; i < tableReg.rows.length; i++)
    {
        cellsOfRow = tableReg.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        found = false;
            compareWith = cellsOfRow[columna].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
            if(compareWith[0]!='<'){
                if (searchText.length == 0 || (compareWith.indexOf(searchText) > -1))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        if(found)
        {
            tableReg.rows[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
            tableReg.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

al cual llamaba mas o menos asi en javascript-html:

```
<input placeholder="Buscar" onkeyup="buscador(this,0)" type="text" class="form-control" >
```

Y como entenderán `this` me enviaba al `input` y a partir de ahí hacia la búsqueda, pero ahora hago algo similar en react pero no me funciona:

```
<input placeholder="Buscar" onChange={()=>buscador(this,0)} type="text" className="form-control"/>
```

pero en este caso `this` ya no es el `input` que yo esperaba, la verdad no se que es lo que llega(ya lo vi en consola no se que seria.), pero lo que quisiera conseguir es enviar el input en esa variable.¿Como lo logro?

Comment: el this es de javascript....no de React, u creo que seria `onChange={buscador}`

Comment: @JackNavaRow Se refiere a que en jQuery `this` es el elemento del DOM mientras que en React es el componente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La manera más sencilla es leer el target del paramétro evento que toda función *event handler* recibe:

```
<input placeholder="Buscar" onChange={(e)=>buscador(e.target,0)} type="text" className="form-control"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo es lo que buscaba.